# Postgres configuration, incoming connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Hello I'm trying to figure out the best way to allow connection from certain ips/hosts to my db instance.

I've got an api(s) pointing to the database and right now we do something like this (pg_hba.conf) :

```
host    prod_db   prod_user         xxx.xxx.77.xx/32        password
```

And since the api are getting deployed in cloud and with new instances, having new ips, we kind of change this config every time we deploy, which is not very good, cause we have to restart the db server and therefore have to put the whole eco system in the maintenance mode.

I'm just reading this :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

This bit looks appealing to me:

```
# Allow any user from hosts in the example.com domain to connect to
# any database if the user's password is correctly supplied.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             .example.com            md5
```

So this means any incoming connection from `api.example.com` or `api1.example.com` or any from this domain will be accepted if the password is correct.

But my question is how does the db server know that it's coming from the `something.example.com`.

Does this mean that the server is doing some kind of reverse dns lookup before allowing connection?

Does this assume that example address `123.456.22.11` which points to `api.example.com`, by point I mean A record will be allowed connection from or how this works?

What do I need to do to make this work?

**My ultimate goal is not to have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` every time there is a new api server instance booted up to add that new ip. And not having to restart postgres db instance**

Comment: Right from the link you provided: "*If a host name is specified (anything that is not an IP address or a special key word is processed as a potential host name), that name is compared with the result of a reverse name resolution of the client's IP address (e.g., reverse DNS lookup, if DNS is used)*". Btw: changes in `pg_hba.conf` don't require a Postgres restart, you only need to reload the configuration (`pg_ctl reload ...`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hey man thanks. Can you please make that an answer. Wow I didn't know about the configuration reload, but still it's unnecessary if you can enable domain

Comment: For "cloud" configs it's more typical to permit wider access in `pg_hba.conf` then use your cloud hosting provider's security group / firewall features to control access.